# Python / Selenium - search following elements too too long time

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have selenium find element line: `element.find_elements(By.XPATH, './following::input')`

But somehow it took waaaay to long to search for all next elements on the page (around 2/3 second !!!)

Is it way around it (or I have done something wrong)???

Answer (score 0):

Just make it like this and it will sort this problem (will search for the following 10 elements instead of all)

- `element.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/following::input[position()<=10]')`